# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)'

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

```
enter code here
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTextInTextView();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}        
public void setTextInTextView(){
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rate);
    Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
    tv.setText(""+extra.getString("key"));   
}

public void go(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity2.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
enter code here
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
RatingBar rb;
float str;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
    rb = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.rt);


}

public void submit(View view) {
   String st = String.valueOf(rb.getRating());
   Intent i = new Intent(Activity2.this,MainActivity.class);
   i.putExtra("key",""+st);
   startActivity(i);
}
}
```

I am a beginner to Android App Development. I am trying to send rating from Second Activity to mainActivity using intent. While doing that i am getting error: "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null"

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
public void setTextInTextView(){
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rate);
    Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
    tv.setText(""+extra.getString("key"));   
}
```

to this:

```
public void setTextInTextView(){
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rate);
    Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extra != null)
        tv.setText(""+extra.getString("key"));   
}
```

Comment: Thanks Omid for your reply but still it is showing me the same error.

Comment: call setTextInTextView(); after  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); not before it

Comment: Thanks Omid... I got it.